# Summing the entries in a finite matrix with intger entries

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

Surprisingly I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176810/sum-of-all-elements-in-a-matrix) on MSE: $$\mathrm{tr}(A^T A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_{ij})^2$$ This result serves my purpose. Rather than take it for granted I would like to be able to actually prove this result and I am not certain how to do it. It seems trivial enough but aside for some special cases of $A$ I just can't see it.

Comment: Have you tried simply writing down $\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)$ using the definitions of the trace and of the matrix product?

Comment: I have. It seems if $A$ is diagonal or symmetric it is easy to show.

Comment: It should work perfectly fine for any matrix, even a non-square one.