# All matrix operations conserving sum of matrix elements

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My question is somewhat related to [Sum of all elements in a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176810/sum-of-all-elements-in-a-matrix)

Consider a matrix A, is there any class of matrices, C, such that:

$$grandsum(CA) = grandsum(A)$$, or

$$ e^TCAe = e^TAe $$

That is all the operations where sum of matrix is conserved. What are such C called?

Background: My friend asked me recently regarding a way to represent all arbitrary volume that a chunk of fluid can take in space. His representation includes a square matrix with matrix elements representing solid angles. Deformation of such fluid will conserve volume, which he is representing as sum of individual elements. so while they can change, their sum cannot.

Comment: "volume, which he is representing as a sum of elements", shouldn't the absolute value of the determinant be the right choice?

Comment: In this case yes, I was thinking if more general class of such matrices exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B,C$ be any matrices such that $e = (1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $1$ for $B$. Then the sum of all elements of your matrix $A$ is $e^TAe = (Be)^TA(Ce) = e^T(B^TAC)e$. And hence the matrix $B^TAC$ has the same sum of elements.

Comment: Ca you explain a bit more? I mean Would it not always come out to be I? $$Be = \lambda e$$, there are only one unknown in this equation, wont B= \lambda I?

Comment: B could be the orthogonal projection on $\text{span} (e)$. This clearly does not equal $I$

Comment: Or $B = ((2,-1),(0,1))$ works in $\mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$